# How do I fix the structure issue with converting Infix to Postfix, and then evaluating it into an answer?

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to convert multiple lines of infix into postfix (RPN) separately and then evaluate each line to get their values, but the postfix isn't printing the expression in the right order, the lines aren't being read individually, and the code doesn't move on to the evaluation

```
Stack *s = initStack();
Stack *s_double = initStack();
Queue * q = initQueue();
char symbol; 
//char rpn_storage[1000];
int operand;
char rator;
char temp, temp1;
double carry, carry1;
int priority;
int priority_temp;
in>> symbol;
//Converting Infix to Postfix
while(symbol != '$'){
    cout << "Converting Infix to Postfix" << endl;
    out << "Converting Infix to Postfix" << endl;
    while(symbol != '\n'){
        if (symbol >= '0' && symbol <= '9'){
            out<< symbol;
            cout<< symbol;
            enqueue(q, symbol); 
        }
        if (symbol == '('){
            push(s, symbol);
        }
        if (symbol == ')'){
            temp = peek(s);
            while (temp != '(' && temp != '\0'){
                temp = pop(s);
                out << temp;
                cout << temp;
                enqueue(q, temp);
                if (temp == '\0'){
                    cout << "\n Error: Stack was found to be empty with no left parenthesis found" << endl;
                    //insert escape to outside the function so one can start over - possibly a return here
                }
                temp = peek(s);
            }
        }
        if (symbol == '+' || symbol == '-' || symbol == '*' || symbol == '/' || symbol == '^'){
            temp = peek(s);

            if (symbol == '+' || symbol == '-'){
                priority = 1;
            }
            if (symbol == '*' || symbol == '/' || symbol == '%'){
                priority = 2;
            }
            if (symbol == '^'){
                priority = 3;
            }
            if (temp == '(' || temp == '\0'){
                priority_temp = 0;
            }
            if (temp == '+' || temp == '-'){
                priority_temp = 1;
            }
            if (temp == '*' || temp == '/'){
                priority_temp = 2;
            }
            if (temp == '^'){
                priority_temp = 3;
            }               
            if (priority >= priority_temp){
                push(s, symbol);
            }
            else{
                temp = pop(s);
                out << temp;
                cout << temp;
                enqueue(q, temp);
                temp = peek(s);
                while (temp != '\0'){
                    if (symbol == '+' || symbol == '-'){
                        priority = 1;
                    }
                    if (symbol == '*' || symbol == '/'){
                        priority = 2;
                    }
                    if (symbol == '^'){
                        priority = 3;
                    }
                    if (temp == '(' || temp == '\0'){
                        priority_temp = 0;
                    }
                    if (temp == '+' || temp == '-'){
                        priority_temp = 1;
                    }
                    if (temp == '*' || temp == '/'){
                        priority_temp = 2;
                    }
                    if (temp == '^'){
                        priority_temp = 3;
                    }
                    if (priority >= priority_temp){
                        push(s, symbol);
                    }
                    else{
                        temp = pop(s);
                        out << temp;
                        cout << temp;
                        enqueue(q, temp);
                        temp = peek(s);                     
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
        in>> symbol;    
    }
    if (symbol == '\n'){
        temp = peek(s);
        while (temp != '\0'){
            temp = pop(s);
            out << temp;
            cout << temp;
            enqueue(q, temp);
        }
        out << endl;
        cout << endl;
        enqueue(q, '\n');
    }
    in >> symbol;
}   
enqueue(q, '$');
//Evaluating Postfix
cout << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << "Evaluating Postfix:" << endl;
out << endl;
out << endl;
out << "Evaluating Postfix:" << endl;
symbol = peek_q(q);                 
while(symbol != '$'){

    while(symbol != '\n'){
        if (symbol >= '0' && symbol <= '9'){
            symbol = dequeue(q);
            symbol = symbol - '0';
            push_double(s_double, symbol);  
        }
        if (symbol == '+' || symbol == '-' || symbol == '*' || symbol == '/' || symbol == '^'){
            carry = pop_double(s_double);
            carry1 = pop_double(s_double);
            if (carry == -999 || carry1 == -999){
                cout<< "\n Error: Malformed RPN expression" << endl;
                //Terminate evaluation here - possibly a return function                
            }
            if(symbol == '+'){
                carry = carry + carry1;
                carry1 = -999;
                push_double(s_double, carry);
            }
            if(symbol == '-'){
                carry = carry - carry1;
                carry1 = -999;
                push_double(s_double, carry);
            }
            if(symbol == '*'){
                carry = carry * carry1;
                carry1 = -999;
                push_double(s_double, carry);
            }
            if(symbol == '/'){
                carry = carry / carry1 * 1.0;
                carry1 = -999;
                push_double(s_double, carry);
            }
            if(symbol == '^'){
                carry = pow(carry1, carry);
                carry1 = -999;
                push_double(s_double, carry);
            }
        }   
    }
    carry = pop_double(s_double);
    out << carry << endl;
    cout << carry << endl;
}
```

The code is supposed to print to the screen and into a text file the RPN expressions and then individually go through the RPN expressions to print the corresponding values